# How to create a k-Fold cross validation test for ANN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently trying to apply k-fold cross validation on my ANN Model by using `cross_val_score` function on python. However I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit' method, <keras.callbacks.History object at 0x00000168C79FE850> was passed
```

ANN model:

```
model = build_model()

# Early Stopping
# The patience parameter is the amount of epochs to check for improvement
early_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience = 5)

ann_Model = model.fit(normed_train_data, y, epochs=EPOCHS, 
                    validation_split = 0.2, verbose=0, callbacks=[early_stop, PrintDot()])
plot_history(ann_Model)
```

k-fold cross validation code:

```
#k-fold cross validation
    
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold
from sklearn import metrics
    
scores = cross_val_score(ann_Model, X, y, cv = 5, scoring = 'r2')
```

Any fixes for this issue? Thank you.

Comment: You should use "model", not "ann_Model" in the function

Comment: Could you please provide us with more information for us to look into this issue, please share complete code to replicate the issue.